# Apache did not serve my Django project templates correctly

Tags: python, django, apache, server, apache2

This index.html showed the apache default page.

when I cd the /var/www/html and ls it, it showed the index.html which is the apache default index page.

My question is: What should I do to change my own templates to be the page index page, should I cp the templates folder to this `/var/www/html`, or should I do something in the `project.conf`, or should I change the `chown/chmod` to the templates directory inside my project so that I achieve it?

This is my sites-available/project.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName Server_IP
ServerAlias Server_IP

DocumentRoot /var/www/html #maybe the problem of this line

 Alias /static /home/ME/project/static
        <Directory /home/ME/project/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/ME/project/media
        <Directory /home/ME/project/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


  <Directory /home/ME/project/Project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

ps. When I tried to change the `documentroot` to /home/ME/project_1/templates, the page showed the error of I don't have permission to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, first I'm surprised that you never declare the domain name in your Apache config file, or that you don't use .conf files with reverse proxy.

Second, you should not serve your static dir in your home directly. Most likely the user that run apache and serve the files won't be able to access this directory. Thus the "don't have permission error".

Instead include a

```
python manage.py collecstatic
```

in your CD script (or do it manually each time) so that Django copy the files in your static dir into the STATIC_ROOT setting (in your settings.py). And point this STATIC_ROOT to something like var/www/my-project/static. Then update your apache config file to use this directory for your static file. Ensure that the user running the CD script has the proper permissions to write on this directory. And then it should work.

Here the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have already collected the static file and my static file is already in the project's directory instead of home (it's in home/user/project). My HTML templates also are not in the static folder, does it matter?